# Dictionary property in Cosmos DB using EF

Tags: azure, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have a class as below and try to use EF core framework to store the below model to Cosmos DB. But the the JSON is stored as

```json
{  
  "id": "e6b75f1f-0cc2-488c-9074-62e7e85c727a",
  "Type ": "testType",
  "TagName ": "TagName",
  "DictionaryList ": {}
}
```

```
public class TestDictionary
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,object> DictionaryList { get; set; }
}
```

Problem is that the DictionaryList property doesn't save the data that is passed from api. It always stores as empty object instead of data passed through dictionary

I want my Jason to be stored in cosmos as below

```json
{  
  "id": "e6b75f1f-0cc2-488c-9074-62e7e85c727a",
  "Type ": "testType",
  "TagName ": "TagName",
  "DictionaryList ": {
       “Account number”: “123456”,
    “Check date”:  “11/20/2020”
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to see in DictionaryList output?

Comment: Updated the question with expected output.Thanks

Comment: A collection in ef core for comos db must be a collection of reference types. A dictonary is a collection of value types. This is not supported in ef core for cosmos db yet https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/2895

Comment: I am also interested in this, and since the issues has been closed I assume this should be possible but I am currently in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Only collections of primitive types are supported by EF Core 6, So `DictionaryList` needs to be typed as `Dictionary<string,string>`

`Dictionary<string,object>` is recognized as a nested entity type, you could use it, but you'd need to explicitly configure all the keys that it can contain:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<TestDictionary>()
        .OwnsOne(t => t.DictionaryList, c =>
        {
            c.Property<string>("Type");
            c.Property<string>("TagName");
        });
}
```

Comment: Are there any other libraries capable Of storing like this, something you would recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I later realized that I could using the cosmos sdk insert Dictionary<stringm, object> without any problem, and that Ef core does expose the underlying cosmos client.

So I solved the issue by access the underlying cosmos client, and use that to insert my dictionary.

```
        var cosmosClient = dbContext.Database.GetCosmosClient();
        var container = cosmosClient.GetContainer(  "db", "container");
        await container.CreateItemAsync(new Dictionary<string,object>);
```

works like a charm.

remember the `Id` has to be `id` or atleast serializer has to be told that Id has to be interpreted `id`

Answer (score 0):

```
  bodyBuilder.Property(x => x.SettlementTypeCustomRpcOperation)
                .ToJsonProperty("settlementTypeCustomRpcOperation")
                .HasConversion(
                    v => v != null ? JObject.FromObject(v) : null,
                    v => v != null
                        ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<RPCOperation, SettlementTypeCustomRpcOperation>>(
                            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v))
                        : null
                );
```

Comment: Please add more explanation to your answer to clarify what you're doing here in the above code. Thanks